# jquery select 2 options not getting formatted

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-select2

I have result of this format and could not get the options to load: can you please help me: what should result method look like?

```
          [{"id":2,"name":512843},{"id":2,"name":512844},
           {"id":2,"name":512847},{"id":2,"name":512874},
           {"id":2,"name":512875},{"id":2,"name":512880},
           {"id":2,"name":512884},{"id":2,"name":512886},
           {"id":2,"name":512887},{"id":2,"name":512888},
           {"id":2,"name":512892},{"id":2,"name":512896},
           {"id":2,"name":512907},{"id":2,"name":512910},
           {"id":2,"name":512911},{"id":2,"name":512913},
           {"id":2,"name":512914},{"id":2,"name":512917},
           {"id":2,"name":512925},{"id":2,"name":512930},
           {"id":2,"name":512931},{"id":2,"name":512935}]
```

it just says failed loading

```
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data.items, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.name,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                })
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out the answer,we should have output from json as

```
results = [{"id":2,"name":512847},{"id":2,"name":512874},
           {"id":2,"name":512875},{"id":2,"name":512880},
           {"id":2,"name":512884},{"id":2,"name":512886},
           {"id":2,"name":512887},{"id":2,"name":512888},
           {"id":2,"name":512892},{"id":2,"name":512896},
           {"id":2,"name":512907},{"id":2,"name":512910},
           {"id":2,"name":512911},{"id":2,"name":512913},
           {"id":2,"name":512914},{"id":2,"name":512917},
           {"id":2,"name":512925},{"id":2,"name":512930},
           {"id":2,"name":512931},{"id":2,"name":512935}]
```

when I have it so, everything was in place and select2 started working!

Comment: i don't see a difference - it looks same